# Phonegap facebook plugin error

Tags: javascript, android, facebook, cordova

I am new to phonegap application development.In  my app i have facebook login.
I have added facebookConnectPlugin.js in js folder but it gives error -

```
 ReferenceError: Can't find variable: cordova at file:///android_asset/www/js/facebookConnectPlugin.js:12
```

below is my index.html code -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link href="gk/lib/jquery.mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">

    <script src="ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/facebookConnectPlugin.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).on("mobileinit", function () {
          $.mobile.autoInitializePage = false;
          $.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = false;
        });
         function mobileInitPage() {
           $.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = true;
           $.mobile.initializePage();
        };
      </script>

     <script src="mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false&language=en"> </script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jquery-ui-map.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ui/min/jquery.ui.map.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>

<!-- GK Loader use RequireJS to load module -->
     <script src="docs/release/2.1.11/minified/require.js"></script>

<!--Plug in GK-->
     <script src="components/jquery.gk/jquery.gk.min.js"></script>

<!-- Load GK components -->   
     <script components="http://jqmdesigner.appspot.com/components/gk-chart/linechart.html,http://jqmdesigner.appspot.com/components/gk-ext/raty.html" callback="mobileInitPage" src="http://jqmdesigner.appspot.com/components/gk-loader/gk-loader.js"></script>

<!-- Graph JS Script -->
      <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
      <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>


      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.pubnub.com/pubnub-3.7.4.min.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="js/appNotification.js"></script>

<!-- Export JS  -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/globalObjects.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/appApi.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/application.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/facebook.js"></script>
<script>
</script>
  <title>BrWiki App</title>
  </head>
```

I am not getting why thie error is occure in my app.
App shows alert with message -

> the protocol is not supported gap/ready

Comment: how did you add the plugin? via phonegap add...? try to recompile.. not just run

Comment: i put the facebookConnectPlugin.js in js folder inside www folder. I am not getting "try to recompile.. not just run" your point.Please explain it.

Comment: The error sounds like cordova.js is not property included. Try calling cordova.js before the plugin js. Also sometimes just using newer cordova.js solves some issue.

Comment: Girlie_mac is right you habe to load cordova.js before the Plugin. I didn't notice that. I had sometimes the issue after adding Plugins or New files and just hit run application that the files didn't move/copy to the package. Thats where recompile was helpful